# Women and mayim achronim

Tags: halacha, women, netilat-yadayim-washing

I read that women are obligated in washing *mayim achronim* just as much as men. Where is the halachic source for this?

Comment: מים אחרונים חובה. Why would you need such a source?

Comment: dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18749/759

Comment: @DoubleAA that question seems to be asking for the opposite source.  This seeks that women are obligated, that one seeks that specifically only men are obligated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sources that  men and women are obligated in mayim acharonim are given in a comment to [Women and Mayim Acharonim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18749/women-and-mayim-acharonim). They are: Ben Ish Chai, First Year, Parshat Shelach, #11 and Halacha Berurah 181:1.

[Halichipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mayim_Achronim#cite_ref-4) says that both men and women are obligated in mayim acharonim and gives the following sources:

> Torah Chaim Sofer 181:1, Sh"t Shalmat Chaim 119, Sh"t Yitzchak Yeranen
>   4:35, Sh"t Rivovot Efraim 1:140(3), Sh"t Sh"t Divrei Chachamim (pg 62)
>   in name of Rav Elyashiv, Rav Ovadyah Yosef in Halichot Olam (vol 2
>   Shalach 1), Halacha Brurah 181:1, Hilchot Bat Yisrael (pg 59) in the
>   name of Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurerbach.

For example:

This is the summary of [Sh"t Yitzchak Yeranen 4:35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21373&hilite=b3b8dca8-57c9-4d31-bd3e-001efaa4b757&st=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=200)

> המורם מהאמור: חובה על הנשים כמו האנשים ליטול ידיהם למים  אחרונים לפני
>   ברכת המזון. וכן ראוי לנהוג ולהנהיג. ורוב הנשים בעולם  שלא נהגו ליטול
>   מים אחרונים יש להסביר להן בלשון רכה ואמירה  נעימה שכן ראוי לנהוג.

This is how the [Sh"t Rivovot Efraim 1:140(3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=106) puts it:

> ג. נשאלתי אם אשה חייבת בנטילת מים אחרונים,  והשבתי דכל הטעמים הנאמרים
>   באיש שייך גם כן  באשה ולכן צריכה. וראיתי בס׳ שלמה חדשה חלק ד׳  שכתב
>   בלשון זה בסי׳ ג׳ אות ב׳ בענין מים אחרונים  לאשה דלכאורה בין לטעם והיתם
>   קדושים אלו מים  אחדונים ברכות נ״ג ע״ב ובין לטעם מפני מלח סדומית  חולין
>   ק״ה שווה אשה לאיש. וא״כ יש להם ליטול. שוב  ראיתי במור וקציעה סו״ס קפ״א
>   דכתב דיש להודיע לנשים  דחייבות בנטילת מים אחרונים כמו אנשים.

Comment: @YEZ Thank you very much for the painstaking edit!

Comment: My pleasure - I didn't actually check the original to make sure it was correct, but I'm sure I got the gist of it.