# Explanation for couple not seeing each other before the wedding?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, wedding, see-sight-vision-blind

What is the source and reason for a couple not to see one another before the wedding?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17760

Comment: Worth noting that many do not follow this practice, notable among them Rabbis Moshe Feinstein and Joseph Soloveitchik.

Comment: What are the source for R. Moshe and R. Soloveitchik?

Comment: @mevaqesh See the article cited below, for one. The better question is why you would assume anyone who knew as much Torah as they did would care about this 'custom'?

Answer (score 10):

[*Jewish Action*, Summer 2005 edition](http://www.ou.org/publications/ja/5765/5765summer/), has [a "What's the truth about..." column by Rabbi Dr. Ari Z. Zivotofsky](https://outorah.org/p/5678/) on not meeting for the week preceding the wedding. His main point is the lack of old sources for this custom, but he does cite several newer sources and the reasons they give. See there for the details, but the reasons and post-facto rationales offered are:

- to avoid *dam chimud* (which he cites strong arguments against as a reason for the custom, so I'll ignore it);
- to prevent discussions that will lead to strife (Rabbi E.M.M. Shach; Rabbi Y.S. Elyashiv, who therefore bans communication by telephone also);
- to allow the couple time apart for introspection (Rabbi *Binyamin* Forst);
- to heighten excitement (unsourced); and
- to prevent premarital relations (unsourced).

And as Rabbi Zivotofsky notes, the last reason should apply only to being alone together, not to simply meeting. Also, see the article for reasons the custom does not exist at all and for rabbis quoted as saying it does not (but also some who defended it).

As always, consult your rabbi for a practical ruling.

Comment: Copy-pasted (with some changes) from [my own answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17764) to an older question, which see for additional contributor information.

Comment: Thanks; just can't help myself but to shout out that "those rabbis who say there's no such custom" includes Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (orally, not in writing). Don't get me wrong, it's still the standard custom, and CYLOR.

Comment: @Shalom There is a custom (used to be more popular) to have the bride and groom have a party the night before the wedding https://www.hamichlol.org.il/%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C