# What is a Shabbos Kallah?

Tags: minhag, marriage, wedding, simchah-joy-happiness

A common tradition that I have observed is for a kallah to have a "Shabbos Kallah" on the shabbos before her wedding. What exactly is a shabbos kallah and why do people have them?

Comment: is it more than just an analog to the aufruf which is called in some circles a shabbat chatan? http://www.jewishtreats.org/2009/12/shabbat-kallah.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufruf

Comment: @Dan, I don't know?

Comment: Its other name (in Yiddish) is a forshpiel. From what I understand, typically all the girls/women in the community are invited to this event, even those not invited to the wedding. Not sure what customs are observed at it other than possibly eating sweet food

Answer (score 4):

During the week before the wedding the Chasson and Kallah do not see each other, so she can't go to the Aufruf.

Instead they hold a Shabbos Kallah for her. There is no source that I could find that requires this, it's just something people do to make the Kallah happy.

Note that this is an Ashkenazi custom, Sefardim don't have an Aufruf or a Shabbos Kallah.

Comment: What? The Ashkenazi custom is for them not to see each other for a week before the wedding? I don't think so. Neither did Rabbis Moshe Feinstein, Joseph or Aharon Solovei(t)chik and others. Perhaps you should limit your custom's scope.

Comment: @DoubleAA You misread it, the Ashkenazi custom is to do an Aufruf.

Comment: Then who are you saying follows the custom of not seeing each other? Is this answer only explaining the origin of Shabbos Kallah only in that group, or claiming that the notion only applies in that group?

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems like it began because of the custom of not seeing each other, then spread to everyone who does an Aufruf, even those who do not have the separation custom.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25716