# Is it permitted to wear leather belts on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, clothing, yom-kippur, inuy-affliction

Does the prohibition of leather on Yom Kippur only apply to shoes/footwear?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is permitted to wear leather belts on Yom Kippur. According to [this article](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/images/ja/fall11/76-79.pdf)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ by [Rabbi Ari Zivotofsky](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/electronic-communication-immediately-before-wedding#comment41344_17764) (published in the Fall 2011 edition of Jewish Action), there is a common misconception that leather belts may not be worn on Yom Kippur, but that is incorrect, and the only leather items that may not be worn on the fast day are shoes.