# Why don't women drink alcohol (other than kiddush wine) in shul?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shabbat, women, liquor-beer

I've noticed that in Orthodox shuls, it's common for men to drink alcohol (such as a shot of scotch or vodka or perhaps a liqueur), other than just kiddush wine, especially after Shacharis on Shabbos. However, I've never seen women doing this (or even drinking shots on Purim, for that matter). Why is this? Is there a source in halacha against women drinking alcohol in public? Is it just assumed to be contrary to modesty? Or is it just that, in American culture, women don't tend to (or are not expected to) like hard liquor by itself?

Comment: Regarding temperance for women, see [*K'suvos* 65a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=65&format=text) (אין פוסקין יינות לאשה, etc.).

Comment: Maybe they have more self control?

Comment: Maybe they don't view Shul as a pub?

Comment: This question is sooo backwards...

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17294/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4844/759

Comment: Alternatively, consider reframing to: "I've noticed that in Orthodox shuls, it's uncommon for women to drink alcohol other than just kiddush wine. However, I've seen men doing this. Why is this? Is there a source in halacha that encourages men to drink alcohol in public?"

Comment: Good point, Double AA and Fred, but I'm sure some women, from a feminist standpoint, have looked at this and thought, "Hey, that's not fair -- I should be able to have a shot of whiskey too if I feel like it!"

Comment: @Kordovero They might have thought that even without being feminists. Women can be alcoholics too, independent of their politics.

Comment: Fred, I don't know of any source in halacha, but this is how Chabad.org charitably explains this practice: "Wine's ability to bring joy is because it relaxes our inhibitions and weakens the body's natural defenses. This 'weakening of the body' allows the soul to shine through. After taking a l'chaim one is more easily inspired, because the body offers less resistance. This obviously applies only when one drinks in moderation, and on special, holy occasions in an attempt to make them a bit more festive and to introduce an inspirational ambiance."

Comment: @Kordovero There is no obligation of *simcha* (as such) on Shabbos more than on any other day of the week.

Comment: ...Actually, it's not so clear cut, but most opinions seem to support the claim in my above comment, at least as it pertains to drinking wine.

Comment: Better question: Why do men drink alcohol during davening?  | Having spent some time on a college campus, I can assure you that Jewish women drink alcohol just as much as men, even in public settings.

Comment: It is an inyan from tznius, not purely sociological. A number of strong halachic sources for women's not drinking to excess or ~at all are provided in the answers here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/is-there-any-source-that-says-that-women-should-should-not-get-drunk-on-purim . (The actual Shevet Halevi citation may be 101:18)

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of shules where women drink alcohol and there are plenty of shules where alcohol is not publicly on display.

This is purely sociological.

Comment: Is it totally random, or is there some pattern? For example, have you ever been at a chassidic shul in which women were drinking l'chayims on Shabbos? I would think this would be less likely.