# How does one who can hold his liquor afflict himself on Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

According to [the answers to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55200/gzeira-shava-by-purim), one is obligated to afflict himself on Purim. The achroynim say that one fulfills this obligation by getting drunk.
However, the true affliction only occurs on the *fifteenth* of Adar when the hangover sets in. Is the mitzvah really to afflict oneself on the 15th, or is there something else we must do on fourteenth in order to fulfill the mitzvah?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Its not the אחרונים but the אחרים

Answer (score 5):

[Rashi](http://www.royalwine.com/wines/wineries/rashi-winery) holds that wine must be unbearably sweet.  ([Rabbi Manischewitz](http://www.manischewitzwine.com/products/products.htm?month=1&day=27&year=1985) was incredibly machmir for this Rashi.) He also holds ([s.v. לאבסומי](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=7b&format=pdf)) that the mitzvah is to get drunk on wine.  So we afflict ourselves in the drinking itself by consuming tons of unbearably sweet wine.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Peula Nimsheches from the 14th.

It's like the Mitzva of eating good food on Shabbos. The Mitzva isn't fulfilled by *eating* on Shabbos. It's fulfilled by *cooking* on Friday to have food on Shabbos. The eating on Shabbos is only to ensure that the food cooked on Friday is going to be for Shabbos. In other words, if one doesn't eat on Shabbos it would turn out that you cooked on Friday for Sunday.

Answer (score -1):

(what not to do)

There is a story about a sage who killed his friend on Purim and brought him back to life. Clearly this afflicted his friend. The friend played it safe the next Purim. I don't recommend this to anyone who can hold their liqour, since there are better ways to accomplish the mitzvah.

edit: I had heard this about a year ago, but this site informs me that it was Rabba and Rav Zeira from the Gemara Megillah 7b.

Comment: This strikes me as a serious answer to the non-Purim-Torah question, "Should a person get drunk on Purim?" Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55567/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13844/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35245/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14794/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12034/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6393/.